# Tiff format in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix. This matrix is full of numbers from zero to 1. I wanted to create a figure:

```
A = zeros(100,100); %just an example matrix that should produce a white tiff-image 
figure(1)
image(A)
```

Sadly it produces a dark violet. But in .tiff 0 means white. How can I produce a grayscale image with 0 = white and 1 = black?

Comment: Yes, I know, I could use inwrite(). But I want to use figure().

Comment: It looks like you are confusing figure _handling_ with figure _saving_. The command `figure` in Matlab creates an interactive figure window. In your example, it's a 100x100 image full of zeros. What color it displays as depends on what colormap you are using. Please read the documentation for the functions [figure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html), [image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) and [saveas](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html), and re-formulate your question.

Comment: “But in .tiff 0 means white.” This is true only if the MinIsWhite tag value is given. This is usually not the case, only for the fax-style format.

Comment: Also, when you [edit] your question as suggested in an earlier comment, please make your question explicit. Currently you are asking “So I hope you see my problem?” The answer to this question is “no” for most people, maybe someone would answer “yes”, but nobody can answer with something that is useful to you because you are not asking the right question.

Comment: You may use `imshow(A)` or `image(A);colormap(gray)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display an image, use `imshow`. Typing `imshow(A)` will display 0 as black and 1 as white, and intermediate values as increasingly bright gray values. This is the standard convention.

You need to show 0 as white and 1 as black, the reverse of the standard convention. You can accomplish this for example by inverting the image:

```matlab
imshow(1-A);
```